# JSON - look up values in array

Tags: json, json.net

With the following json

```
{
    "Count":0,
    "Message":{
        "AppId":0
    },
    "Data":"[{\"application_name\": \"Grand Central\",\"feature_name\": \"1 Click Fix\",\"access_type_id\": 2,\"member_name\": \"GC_Remote_Support_Security\"},{\"application_name\": \"Grand Central\",\"feature_name\": \"Account Details\",\"access_type_id\": 2,\"member_name\": \"GC_Remote_Support_Security\"},{\"application_name\": \"Grand Central\",\"feature_name\": \"Account Summary\",\"access_type_id\": 2,\"member_name\": \"GC_Remote_Support_Security\"}]"
}
```

how do I go through the Data array, in the most succinct coding manner possible, to see if any feature_name matches a given string?

Comment: Your have not provided valid JSON, and you have not shown any attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Re my previous comment: I have corrected the former, the latter is on you. Nesting JSON in JSON is not the best idea either, FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your JSON contains nested, quoted JSON, you will need nested deserializations using [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to parse your `Data` array.  Having done so, you can use [use `SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) to query with a [JSONPath query](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to find nested properties named `feature_name`, then check their value:

```
        var testString = "Account Summary";
        var found = JToken.Parse(JObject.Parse(jsonString)["Data"].ToString()).SelectTokens("..feature_name").Any(t => (string)t == testString);
        Debug.Assert(found == true); // No assert.
```

**Update**

If you want the all `JObject` with a `"feature_name"` property matching a given value, you can do:

```
        var foundItems = JToken.Parse(JObject.Parse(jsonString)["Data"].ToString())
            .SelectTokens("..feature_name")
            .Where(t => (string)t == testString)
            .Select(t => t.Ancestors().OfType<JObject>().First()) // Get the immediate parent JObject of the matching value
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution! I've learned in 5 minutes more about JSON/LINQ than I could have in 5 hours browsing the net, not having any real idea what to look for.

Comment: And how would I then find the matching item for the same feature_name?